# Debug REST Service with additional parameters in VS

Tags: c#, debugging, wcf-rest

I am implementing a REST Service which takes also additional params. My issue is that I cant step into a particular method while debugging. I attached the relevant process to VS and for one call debugging works fine. Lets first see what causes my issue:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      UriTemplate = "/mrn/{PatNr}")]
List<LaborDataContract> LaborResultDetailsByPatNr(string PatNr);

[OperationContract]
[WebGet(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
      UriTemplate = "/mrn/{PatNr}&FromDate={FromDate}&ToDate={ToDate}")]
List<LaborDataContract> LaborResultDetailsByPatNrDatePeriod(string PatNr, string fromDate, string todate);
```

Implementation has been done well for above methods.

This service call works properly:

```
http://localhost:50358/UszDataService/mrn/10171098
```

Calling above URI I can step into the code, so debugging works fine.

But if I call the following URI, debugging always steps into the above method instead of the one defined in the contract:

```
http://localhost:50358/UszDataService/mrn/10171098&FromDate=2017-03-01&Todate=2017-03-03
```

The confusing thing is that in the parameter (PatNr) of the method which is called I see the following when I check the content:

```
"10171098&FromDate=2017-03-01&Todate=2017-03-03"
```

Do I miss something defining the contract with multiple params?

Any help is very appreciated.

regards
Sandro

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with ? for the first query parameter and then with & for the next ones

http://localhost:50358/UszDataService/mrn/10171098?FromDate=2017-03-01&Todate=2017-03-03

Comment: Hi Andreas

Thank you for the quick reply :)

Arrghh...yes I see, fixed. But still it calls the wrong method.

Caling the url steps always into the method with only one param

Comment: @SandroColletti the two templates are practically the same url that's why. Query params do not define the url. This http://localhost:50358/UszDataService/mrn/10171098?FromDate=2017-03-01&Todate=2017-03-03 and http://localhost:50358/UszDataService/mrn/10171098?FromDate=2017-03-01&Todate=2017-03-03&Third=3 are the same. You will have to change the template for the second one

Comment: Also you don't need the query params in the template. Just put them as arguments and it will pick them up from the query parameters

Comment: ahhhhh...I see

don't shure i understand exactly what you mean in your last reply. Could you maybe provide some additional explanation? would be great.

Comment: If you want to use query parameters instead of url parameters then you do not to define them in the url template, you just need to have them in the argument list of the method.

`UriTemplate = "/mrn2/{PatNr}")]
List<LaborDataContract> LaborResultDetailsByPatNrDatePeriod(string PatNr, string fromDate, string todate);`

this should be fine

Comment: just tried but I get this error now:

Operation 'LaborResultDetailsByPatNr' in contract 'IUszDataProvisionService' uses GET, but also has body parameter 'FromDate'. GET operations cannot have a body. Either make the parameter 'FromDate' a UriTemplate parameter, or switch from WebGetAttribute to WebInvokeAttribute. 

I have already changed to WebInvoke, but still not working then

actually investigating, but maybe you have a hint?

Comment: Sorry. It seems I was wrong. Try this `UriTemplate = "/mrn/{PatNr}?FromDate={FromDate}&ToDate={ToDate}")]`